# How do i pass command line arguments to Xcode project through AppleScript?

Tags: xcode, command-line, applescript

I am trying to set command line arguments for Xcode project related to iPhone Simulator Application.

When i try to run the following script the line 
"make new launch argument with properties{name:"file:///Users/aakash/Desktop/sample_h.html",active:yes} "

gives error:
execution error: Xcode got an error: Can’t make or move that element into that container. (-10024)

Here's the script:

```bash
!/bin/zsh

BUILD_PATH=$(dirname $0)

while [[ -z $BUILD_FILE && $BUILD_PATH != "/" ]]; do
    BUILD_FILE=$(find $BUILD_PATH -name '*.xcodeproj' -maxdepth 1)
    BUILD_PATH=$(dirname $BUILD_PATH)
done

if [[ -z $BUILD_FILE ]]; then
    echo "Couldn't find an xcode project file in directory"
    exit 1
fi

open -a Xcode "$BUILD_FILE"

BUILD_FILE=${BUILD_FILE//\//:}

SIMULATOR_SDKS=( /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/*.sdk )

SIMULATOR_SDK=${SIMULATOR_SDKS[-1]} 
SIMULATOR_SDK_STRING=$(basename ${(L)SIMULATOR_SDK%.[a-z]*})

if [[ -z $SIMULATOR_SDK ]]; then
    echo "Couldn't find a simulator SDK"
    exit 1
fi

echo $BUILD_FILE
echo $BUILD_PATH

osascript <<SCRIPT
application "iPhone Simulator" quit
application "iPhone Simulator" activate


tell application "Xcode"
    open "$BUILD_FILE"
    set targetProject to project of active project document

    tell targetProject
        set active build configuration type to build configuration type "Debug"
        set active SDK to "$SIMULATOR_SDK_STRING"
        set value of build setting "SDKROOT" of build configuration "Debug" of active target to "$SIMULATOR_SDK"
        make new launch argument with properties{name:"file:///Users/aakash/Desktop/sample_h.html",active:no}

        if (build targetProject) is equal to "Build succeeded" then
                launch targetProject
        else
                application "iPhone Simulator" quit
        end if
    end tell
end tell
SCRIPT
```

Any Clues???
Is there any other way to set arguments for Xcode Project or am i doing it wrong?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For building from the command line, I generally use a Makefile that launches [xcodebuild](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcodebuild/), the command-line front-end to Xcode. You could also use a zsh script to do the same thing, if you prefer. It's pretty easy to set project build options using the command-line tool.

Comment: xcodebuild does not work with iphone simulator app.You have to launch "build and go" in Xcode to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should make active executable as the container instead of Xcode application

```
tell application "Xcode"
set targetProject to project of active project document
set targetExecutable to active executable of targetProject
tell targetExecutable
make new launch argument with properties {name:"new argument", active:true}
end tell
end tell
```

this still works for Xcode 3.* but no long work with Xcode 4.*